# Алгоритм выводящий минимальное количество пар, необходимых для удовлетворения всех поступивших заказов

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Нуждаюсь в помощи. Есть задание, но идей как реализовать нету. Буду рад помощи, если не трудно.

**Входные данные (2): количество циклопов N; массив N чисел, каждый элемент которого указывает на рекомендованную оптическую силу линзы для каждого i-го Циклопа.**

**В одном городе на Земле живут Циклопы. У большинства Циклопов есть проблемы со зрением, поэтому им рекомендовано носить контактные линзы. При этом, если Циклопу рекомендовано ношение линз в К диоптрий, его устроят линзы в К-1, К, К+1 диоптрии. Циклопы очень боятся, что о них узнают люди, поэтому заказывают линзы в обычных человеческих магазинах парами одинаковой оптической силы. Один Циклоп решил собирать заказы и оптимизировать процесс закупки линз так, чтобы покупать как можно меньше пар, при этом удовлетворить все поступившие заказы.**

**Требуется написать алгоритм на javascript, выводящиЙ минимальное количество пар,  необходимых для удовлетворения всех поступивших заказов.**

*Пример: например, для 5-ти Циклопов с диоптриями [1, -1, 2, З, -3], достаточно купить З пары линз (О диоптрий удовлетворят 1-го и 2-го Циклопов, 2 или З диоптрия удовлетворят 3-го и 4-го Циклопов, -2 или -3 или -4 диоптрии удовлетворят 5-го Циклопа, но 1 линза будет не задействована —это нормально).*

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужно написать алгоритм который который будет выводить минимальное количество пар линз для циклопов. На примере из условия, есть 5 циклопов, у всех разные диоптрии. У первого 1, у второго -1, у третьего 2, у четвертого 3 и у пятого -3. Нужен алгоритм который будет находить минимальное количество пар линз. Одна пара лин для двух циклопов.

Answer (score 2):

Одна из разновидностей задачи покрытия.

Создадим массив пар требуемых отрезков оптической силы для циклопов. Для каждого циклопа добавляем триплет{K[i]-1; 1; i} (левый конец) и триплет {K[i]+1; -1; i} (правый конец). Сортируем по первому полю, при равенстве раньше пойдёт пара с +1.

Создадим также массив пометок (boolean) и стек.

Пройдём по массиву по порядку. Если встретили левый конец, кладём его номер (третье поле) в стек.

Если встретили правый **непомеченный конец**, то: извлекаем из стека всё, что там есть, подсчитывая количество (M) и помечая соотв ячейки в массиве пометок. Добавляем к результату (M+1)/2 (получается целочисленное деление с округлением вверх).

А если правый помеченный - то ничего не делаем.

Comment: А можно кодом, если не трудно? Просто я все равно не совсем понимаю.

Comment: А что неясно? Можно попроще - для каждого правого конца во втором цикле проверять, сколько ещё циклопов сюда же попадают и помечать их как удовлетворенных. Это медленнее, но работоспособно.

Comment: @LEH1CH в комментарии под вопросом вы просили алгоритм =). А код - не алгоритм.

Comment: как то перемудрили  =)

Comment: @tym32167 Не исключено. Метод, как и у вас, жадный, только я имел в голове произвольные интервалы. Контрпримеров к вашему не придумал, хорошо получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы отсортировал просто диоптрии циклопов и покупал бы очки для соседей.

Пример на C#

```
int PairsCount(int[] data)
{
    // Сортирую
    Array.Sort(data);

    var ret = 0;
    int ind = 0;

    while (ind < data.Length)
    {
        if (ind == data.Length - 1)
        {
            ret++;
            break;
        }

        // проверяю соседей (ind и ind+1 индексы)
        // покупаю пару либо для одного, либо для двух циклопов
        if (data[ind + 1] - data[ind] <= 2)     
            ind += 2;       
        else        
            ind += 1;   

        ret++;
    }
    
    // конец
    return ret;
}
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(PairsCount(new[] { 1, -1, 2, 3, -3 }));
```

Вывод

```
3
```